Multi-dimensional trace over unit spheres
I have to compute multi-dimensional integrals over unit spheres. Let me start with what should be simplest case:
$
I_1(d) = \int_{B_1^d} d \vec x_1\int_{B_1^d} d \vec x_2\,|\vec x_1 - \vec x_2|^2\tag{1}\label{I1}
$
where $B_1^d$ is the $d$-dimensional ball of unit radius.
Using
$
|\vec x_1 - \vec x_2|^2 = |\vec x_1|^2 + |\vec x_2|^2 - 2 \vec x_1 \cdot \vec x_2
$
the integral over the scalar product should vanish because of symmetry and we obtain
$
I_1(d) =  2V_d\int_{B_1^d}d \vec x\, |\vec x|^2
$
where
$V_d = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2+1)}$
is the volume of the unit ball. Changing variables to spherical coordinates gives
$
I_1(d) = 2 V_d S_d \int_{0}^1 dr \, r^{d+1} = \frac{2V_d S_d}{(d+2)}\tag{2}\label{I1_result}
$
with
$
S_d = d V_d
$
the surface of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
The final goal would be to compute the following `trace'
$
I_k(n_1,\dots,n_k;d) = \int_{B_1^d \times \dots \times B_1^d}\left[\prod_{i=1}^k d \vec x_i\right]|\vec x_1 - \vec x_2|^{2n_1}\dots|\vec x_k - \vec x_1|^{2n_k} \tag{3}\label{Ik}
$
A brute force approach is via expanding the various powers using the binomial and multinomial theorem. Indeed
$
\begin{align}
&|\vec x_i - \vec x_{i+1}|^{2n_i} 
\nonumber
\\
&= (|\vec x_i|^2 + |\vec x_{i+1}|^2 - 2 \vec x_i \cdot \vec x_{i+1}|)^{n_i}
\nonumber
\\
& = \sum_{l_{i_1}+l_{i_2} + l_{i_3} = 3}\binom{n_i}{l_{i_1},l_{i_2},l_{i_3}}|\vec x_i|^{2l_{i_1}}|\vec x_{i+1}|^{2l_{i_2}}(-1)^{l_{i_3}}2^{l_{i_3}}\left(\sum_{j=1}^d \vec x_{i,j}\vec x_{i+1,j}\right)^{l_{i_3}}
\nonumber
\\
& = \sum_{l_{i_1}+l_{i_2} + l_{i_3} = 3}\binom{n_i}{l_{i_1},l_{i_2},l_{i_3}}|\vec x_i|^{2l_{i_1}}|\vec x_{i+1}|^{2l_{i_2}}(-1)^{l_{i_3}}2^{l_{i_3}}\sum_{r_{i_1}+\dots+r_{i_d}=l_{i_3}}\binom{l_{i_3}}{r_{i_1},\dots,r_{i_d}}\prod_{j=1}^d (x_{i,j}x_{i+1,j})^{r_{i_j}}
\end{align}\tag{4}
$
Multiplying $k$ of these factors one needs to integrate the building blocks
\begin{align}
\int_{B_1^d \times \dots \times B_1^d}\left[\prod_{i=1}^k d \vec x_i\right]\prod_{i=1}^k|\vec x_i|^{2l_{i_1}}|\vec x_{i+1}|^{2l_{i_2}}\prod_{j=1}^d (x_{i,j}x_{i+1,j})^{r_{i_j}}\quad , \quad \vec x_{k+1}=\vec x_1\tag{5}
\end{align}
I guess this is doable using some combinatoric argument or maybe exploiting group theoretic arguments based on symmetries (indeed the trace \eqref{Ik} is invariant under permutations).
Any hint for Christmas?
Thank you very much in advance!
